# SAS - How to skip a record when reading in a data file

Tags: sas

I have data that looks something like this:

ID      Test    Date

001      A      9/1/2011 
001      A  10/2/2011 
001      A      9/12/2012 
001      A      10/10/2013 
001   B      10/1/2011 
001      B      1/1/2012 
002      A      10/12/2014
   
002      A      10/13/2014 
002      A       2/2/2015 
002      A  11/15/2015

What I would like to do is read in the first record of ID/Test, and then compare it to the next record of the same ID/Test. If that test date is NOT at least 365 days later then delete it. And then re-test the next record. If it is at least 365 days later, then I will keep it, and **use it as the new comparison date** within that ID/Test group for the next records. But each ID/Test combination will have a varying number of records and dates.

I would like it to end up like this:

ID      Test    Date

001      A      9/1/2011 
 
001      A      9/12/2012 
001      A      10/10/2013 
001   B      10/1/2011 
 002      A      10/12/2014
   
002      A  11/15/2015

Thanks for any help -

*ETA: Code I have tried:*

data want; set have;
lagid=lag(id); lagtest=lag(test); lagdate=lag(date):

if id=lagid AND test=lagtest then days=date-lagdate;

if 1 le days le 365 then delete;

run;

This code only works for pairs that are next to each other. In my sample data it would give me the incorrect results of -

ID      Test    Date

001      A      9/1/2011 
 
001      A      10/10/2013 
001   B      10/1/2011 
 
002      A      10/12/2014

---

ETA: I found a solution using RETAIN and set by ID and Test.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some code?

Comment: I figured it out - ended up using the RETAIN statement to compare dates, and then update the retained variable when the I get to a record I want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

```
data begin;
    input ID Test $ date mmddyy10.; 
    cards;
    001 A 09/01/2011 
    001 A 10/02/2011 
    001 A 09/12/2012 
    001 A 10/10/2013 
    001 B 10/01/2011 
    001 B 01/01/2012 
    002 A 10/12/2014 
    002 A 10/13/2014 
    002 A 02/02/2015 
    002 A 11/15/2015
    ;
run;

proc sort data=begin; by id test date; run;

data processed;
    retain days_since;
    set begin;
        by id test; 
        if first.test then do; /*Prime the flow variable and output the base     values*/
        days_since=date;
        output;
    end;

    if (date-days_since)>=365 then do; 
        days_since = date;
        output;
    end;
    format date yymmdd10.;
run;
```